# do I even need to GROUP BY if I'm selecting a MAX(some_column) in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm going through and optimizing some SQL queries.

In my db, the following two queries return the same thing, but I'm not sure if I'm not seeing something.  If I use MAX(one_of_my_columns), it seems to return 1 row (which is what I want) whether I use GROUP BY or not.  Are these the same:

```
SELECT someThing, someNum, anotherNum, MAX(installDate)
FROM someTable 
WHERE someThing= '123' 
    AND '2018' >= installDate 
    GROUP BY someUniqueID HAVING isEnabled
```

and (one without group by)

```
SELECT someThing, someNum, anotherNum, MAX(installDate)
FROM someTable 
WHERE someThing = '123' 
    AND '2018' >= installDate 
    AND isEnabled
```

also, "isEnabled" is a column with 1 or 0.. I believe this is working as intended in both (only return if 1)

EDIT: made "someUniqueID", someThing... this isn't unique and will have duplicates.
EDIT 2: I meant it returns one row.

Comment: `someUniqueID` reads like there will be never two rows with the same value here. Correct?

Comment: How does a SELECT listing 4 columns result in just one column?

Comment: What is the point of grouping by a column you *explicitly* insure will have only 1 value?

Comment: whoops whoops, sorry, someUniqueID is not really unique.  so there can be several with the same ID..  i was obfuscating and it backfired lol. I'll edit

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause

Comment: also sorry, i meant it returns 1 row.. sorry about not proofreading haha

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Shawn in the comments:
https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause

this seems to sum it up. They are the same thing.